# Cannot access column of data frame

Tags: r

I have some data in a results 3-column data frame  when I print results I see:

```
 results

TIMESTAMP                 SYMBOL_NAME         "t.price"
1 2014-10-17 14:00:00       GOOG                   400.25
```

Notice the "" around the t.price column

When I go to access the t.price column like it comes back null.

```
 results$t.Price
 NULL
```

when I do

```
  names(results)
```

I see

```
[1] "TIMESTAMP"        "SYMBOL_NAME"        "\"t.PRICE\""
```

Can you tell me what is going on and why the "" is appearing or how I can access t.price?

Comment: What happens if you type `results$"t.PRICE"` or `results$\"t.PRICE\"`?

Comment: Something has happened when you have read in the data - a crude, quick fix is to rename your variables via..`names(results) <- c(["TIMESTAMP","SYMBOL_NAME","t.PRICE")`. Also have a look at `str(results)`

Comment: you can also use results[,3] to access that column

Comment: `results$'"t.PRICE"'` and `results[, "\"t.PRICE\""]` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
names(results) <- make.names( names(results) )
```

That's the same function that gets applied when `read.table` and its descendants are used.

Comment: I guess it's not too important, but when I run this I get `X.t.price` for the last column.  Is that what you get?

Comment: I don't have the original object since it wasn't presented in a reproducible form, but yes, that's what I get now that I use `make.names`, and to your next question that's not what I would have predicted.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the extra quotes with `gsub`

```
results
#             TIMESTAMP SYMBOL_NAME "t.price"
# 1 2014-10-17 14:00:00        GOOG    400.25
results$t.price
# NULL
names(results)[3] <- gsub('\"', "", names(results)[3])
results$t.price
# [1] 400.25
```

Just to be safe, you might want to run it on all the names of the data set (just remove both `[3]`).

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the source of your data frame is, it appears that the t.Price column is surrounded by quotation marks. These in turn are escaped by \ as \" as otherwise "" would be the end of a string of 0 length.

Methods to work around this are suggested by the comments, you can access this by the index of the column or by renaming the columns, which can be done by assigning to names.

```
names(results) <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")
```